# How should I connect these kind of cables?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

[image]

I bought this screen from eBay - https://www.ebay.com/itm/183565808942

But I can't seem to connect the cable to the controller board.

How does one connect/disconnect this type of cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the connector sticking out of the screen?

It's a flexible printed circuit (FPC), also known as flexible flat cable (FFC).

Usually the connector on the board will have a locking mechanism. There's a part of the connector with either slides back or up or rotates up. Then you insert the connector, and push back the moving part until it clicks back in place.

This picture from [Omron](https://components.omron.com/connector-basics/part2-omron-connectors/fpc_ffc-connector) gives a couple of examples:

[image]

As you can see, there are different types of connectors with the moving part in different places (there are more), so you'll have to get a look at the connector to find out what moves and how.

Comment: Found the solution! I marked your response as the answer because I found out the name of the connector type and was able to do further searches. In my case, I pushed the black part of the connector towards the edge of the pcb (by the sides), slid the cable in and then pushed the black part back...seems to hold the connection and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I think on this type the black tab lifts up (both sides are connected). I have seen them in laptops. It is like the "traditional rotary connector" except you can't see the middle black part.